# Given that $x^3+x^2=1$, express the infinite product $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)\ldots$ in the form $A+Bx+Cx^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given that $x^3+x^2=1$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, express the infinite product $$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)\ldots$$
>   in the form $A+Bx+Cx^2$.

In the earlier parts of the question, I have already shown that
$$x^4=-1+x+x^2$$
$$x^{-1}=x+x^2$$
$$1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+\ldots=x^2$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=2+2x+x^2$$

I also know that
$$1+x=\frac{1}{1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+\ldots}.$$

Can anyone give me a hint? Perhaps there is a way to do it using the previous parts, but I cannot see how.

Comment: The two non-real roots of $x^3+x^2-1$ have absolute value $> 1$, so this infinite product can't converge if $x$ is one of them.  You must assume $x$ is the real root.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry,  yes, I should have specified $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)(1+x^8)\cdots=\frac1{1-x}, \qquad |x|<1,
$$ then insert
$$
x=\frac1{x+x^2}
$$ in the preceding identity.

Comment: Where does the second equation come from?

Comment: Typo corrected, thanks.

Comment: Why is $(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^4)\ldots=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$?

Comment: Please, have a look here :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575082/product-prod-n-0-infty1z2n or here :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769861/closed-form-for-prod-i-0-infty1x2i